# Fetch new data when the component props change

Tags: reactjs

I have 4 buttons and upon clicking the button a component is called where I show different data based on which button was clicked.

For the first time when I click the button, that component's constructor and `componentWillMount()` function is called but after that, It's not called until I refresh the page or navigate to different page and come back.

So, Is there any way to call the component's `componentWillMount()` function or constructor each time that particular component is called?

I am not attaching code as the question is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Sounds like you should change the state in the click handler so react will re-rende the page

Comment: @Raulucco But then it would re-render the whole main page.

Comment: Not necessary, if you change the state of the parent it will only rerender that node and its children. but it depends on your tree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its looks like that You are supplying different props to the component and hence you need to make use of `componentWillReceiveProps` together with `componentDidMount`

According to the documentation

> **componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)**
>
> `componentWillReceiveProps()` is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare `this.props`
>   and `nextProps` and perform state transitions using `this.setState()`
>   in this method.
>
> **componentDidMount()**
>
> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request.

So you need to update check if your props have changed in the child components `componentWillReceiveProps` and take action based on it. Since `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called the first time the component is mounted you need to make use of `componentDidMount` as well since it is called only on the first render

Answer (score 1):

No, as the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) states the component is only mounted once in the page lifecycle.

I think you probably need the componentWillUpdate event instead. Make sure the shouldComponentUpdate method returns true when needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.. In `componentWillUpdate` you can't change state. So I used `componentWillReceiveProps` and it worked.